# how to get i month before date from current date in java.my periodtype is month.os iwant 1 month before date from start date

Tags: java

```
if(request.getParameter("PeriodType")==""){
                if(request.getParameter("startdate")!=null)
                    StartDate = request.getParameter("startdate");
                if(request.getParameter("endDate")!=null)
                    EndDate = request.getParameter("endDate");
```

Comment: What is your question, It is not pretty clear

Comment: try ask your question not in the Title, then you can use more sentences

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use external libraries, you can do it with `GregorianCalendar`:

```
int i = 5;
Date date = new Date();
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(date);
gc.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, -i);
Date dateBefore = gc.getTime();

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(dateBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this. It's a powerful library for date management. Here is code to get date one month before :

```
//replace [date-pattern] by your date format eg "yyyy-MM-dd"
DateTime time = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("[date-pattern]").parseDateTime("startdate")
DateTime oneMonthBefore = time.minusMonths(1)
```

I encourage you to browse the well-written [javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html)